# how to establish remote MySQL connection from Rapidminer? user not known?

Tags: mysql, rapidminer

I want to connect to a mysql database from Rapidminer, I am not sure, but to have acces to databases, I have to execute a GRANT ALL string on my mySQL machine first, is that right?

it goes like:
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@IPADRESS IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
where IPADRESS should be ipadress of my remote computer, and password is the password of the root login of my mySQL Workbench, is that correct?

but what is the user? I didn't create a user before, and I am trying from rapidminer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify a little your question, because I am not sure, if I understand correctly you question.

But: every MySQL connection should have following things:

1. database name
2. host
3. username
4. password
5. table name

An user you can create from MySQL workbench, not from RapidMiner. I think, the same database can have multiple users with respective passwords.

Comment: yeah its solved now, it just wasn't clear to me what was meant by user... but its just a created user in mySQL Workbench..